# Iterate through paragraphs

Tags: javascript, html, css, paragraph

I've been using javascript (with a very limited knowledge) to swap images but now I want to do it with text.

My question is, if I have 10 different paragraphs (link 1 shows paragraph 1, link 2 shows paragraph 2 etc), I don't understand where I can 'type' them. My images obviously link to a ready made file but I want my text to remain as text and I'm not sure how I assign this in either CSS or HTML etc.

CODE USED:

So far I have my CSS code to define my text content (that I want to change depending on the clicking) and my map content where I'm controlling the change in text:

```
    #content 
#content div {float:left;}  
#content_map {width:595px; height: 595px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-right:15px;}      
    #content_text {width:290px; height: 595px; margin-bottom: 15px;}
#content_profile {width:900px; height: 755px; margin-bottom: 15px;}
```

So my html so far for the map 'hotspots' are as an example:

```
  <area shape="circle" coords="276,326,15" href="#" alt="Kinnloch" onclick="MM_swapImage('stboswells_01','','discover_kinnloch.png',1)"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="202,264,11" href="#" alt="Lochinver" onclick="MM_swapImage('stboswells_01','','discover_lochinver.png',1)"/>
```

...
etc

so basically I'm swapping images in the 'profile' div by the coordinates on the 'map' div and what i want to do is use these coordinates to also swop in text in my 'text' div so the first set of coords would change my text div to say 'Discover Kinnloch' and the second set of coordinates would change my text div to say 'Discover Lochinver' etc...

Comment: *"...but I want my text to remain as text..."* what does this mean?  And are you saying first there is a bunch of images and clicking one replaces that one image with a block of text? Or vice versa?  Please be more clear and include some code for us

Comment: @Deryck I believe he means that he doesn't want to turn the text into images

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like you want expanding sections.

You could have the content already in the html hidden by CSS, and show it via javascript. Here's an example using jQuery.

```
<div class="container">
     <a href="#">Header 1</a>

    <p class="container-body">This is a test.</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
     <a href="#">Header 2</a>

    <p class="container-body">This is another test.</p>
</div>
```

Hidden by CSS:

```
.container-body {
    display: none;
}
```

And toggled by the JavaScript:

```
$(".container a").click(function () {
    $(".container-body", $(this).parent()).slideToggle();
});
```

Here's a quick fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/yv9QG/

Alternatively, if you're talking about swapping text in a target space it's only a few minor changes and you end up with something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yv9QG/1/

Comment: thank you for this I'm going to add my code that I'm using so far as I don't think I've explained myself very well.